# How many mg of acetic acid are in 1 Goli apple cider vinegar gummy?

Tags: vinegar, nutrient-composition, apples

[The label](https://images.ulta.com/is/image/Ulta/2581702_prod_altimg_1?op_sharpen=1&resMode=bilin&qlt=85&wid=800&hei=800&fmt=jpg) says "Apple Cider Vinegar (5% acetic acid) 500 mg". 
Does one gummy have 25mg of acetic acid or 500mg of acetic acid?

Comment: If two gummies have 1,000 mg vinegar that's 5% acetic acid, then one has 500 mg.  500 x 0.05 = 25 mg.

Comment: please realize that the answer you accepted is completely 100% wrong and makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Acetic acid is a component of apple cider vinegar, and the ingredients list claims 5% - typically calculated weight by weight - that's 5 mg acetic acid per 100 mg of apple cider vinegar. @Bob Brown put the answer in a comment above already, 25 mg for one gummy.

The answer from @Regjohn1 completely missed the important 5% bit, and if it was actually 500 mg dry acetic acid per 500 mg apple cider vinegar per gummy, 1) that's legally not apple cider vinegar, and 2) it would be highly hazardous to consume.

Comment: I would certainly hope that this is so. But it seems that these gummies are intended as some kind of dietary supplement, and not as a purely culinary candy. In that case, the producers may have intentionally put that much acetic acid into them. The labeling might mean that the acetic acid was derived from the vinegar (I don't know the legal requirements, especially since they don't seem to have been produced in regulation-heavy parts of the world) and the hazard is debatable, at least in the short term. So while I want you to be right, I wouldn't put my hand into the fire for it.